# How to delete or update using inner join in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I need to delete some records using inner join in Entity Framework.

For example, I have `User`, `Role` and `UserRoleMapping` tables:

```
User => Id, Name
Role => Id, Name
UserRoleMapping => Id, UserId, RoleId
```

Now I need to delete the users who belong to role with Id = 2.

I need to fire the query as shown below

```
Delete user 
from User 
inner join UserRoleMapping on User.Id = UserRoleMapping.UserId 
where UserRoleMapping.RoleId = 2
```

Is this is possible in Entity Framework?

Comment: For this kind of operations it is worth checking out https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus.

Answer (score 2):

In EF you need first load entities, select items and then `DeleteObject` . You need do it like:

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
   var item = (from user in context.User
   join userRoleMapping in context.UserRoleMapping on user.Id equals userRoleMapping.UserId
   where userRoleMapping.RoleId == 2
   select user).ToList().ForEach(context.User.DeleteObject);


   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note:

> `ObjectContext.DeleteObject(entity)` marks the entity as Deleted in the context. (It's EntityState is Deleted after that.) If you call `SaveChanges` afterwards EF sends a SQL DELETE statement to the database. If no referential constraints in the database are violated the entity will be deleted, otherwise an exception is thrown

or

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
 {
    var items = (from user in context.User
    join userRoleMapping in context.UserRoleMapping on user.Id equals userRoleMapping.UserId
    where userRoleMapping.RoleId == 2
    select user).ToList();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
      context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

or using `ExecuteStoreCommand`, here you find [more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
    context.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM USER INNER JOIN USERROLEMAPPING ON USER.ID = USERROLEMAPPING.USERID WHERE USERROLEMAPPING .ROLEID = {0}", customId);
}
```

Comment: There will be a list of Users, But the following query will delete only one record.

Comment: @GopinathNavaneethan  Check update it remove all items from select.

Comment: the above code will work but performance wise it fail. That is why I need inner join query with delete:-(

Comment: @GopinathNavaneethan You can try also `ExecuteStoreCommand()` should be more optimal

Comment: I am sorry for this, But I need the query more generic also.

Comment: You don't need "var item = " in the first example, because you do iteration in the same LINQ statement. You need it in the second example though.